# MariaDB and MySQL in mixed environments - Replication issue with master/slave design

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb, replication

I am designing a data replication solution across timezones and have run into the issue where I can only run and old version of MySQL (5.6) in one location, whereas the other two have MariaDB 10.2.

Now, I have read the information about [Replication Compatibility](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) over at MariaDB. Clearly I can't use MariaDB as a master and MySQL as a slave.

**Intermediate solution based on Bash scripts**

Yet, I want to use my EU server as a master and that is running MariaDB. So I'm now contemplating a way around the limitation. So far I have come up with an intermediate data storage solution in the overseas server, where data is shuffled periodically using my own Bash data migration scripts over a low bandwidth link.

**MariaDB is required in the primary location**

I have to use MariaDB in my primary location because I'm using the ColumnStore database there. That is unconditional as part of the application design.

**Does this situation ring a bell?**

Do you have experience with similar situations and would you mind sharing some inspiration as for how you did it?

My best solution so far is with Bash scripts that are cronned, where MySQL data is dumped (`mysqldump`) and transferred over a low bandwidth link, then merged with the master (ColumnStore storage engine). I'm looking at a T+1 data lag between my primary location and the secondary location that is running MySQL.

Any high level design thoughts or shared experience is highly appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: Did you disable GTID?  (The two have different implementations of such.)